# Is there any compatible SwiftyJSON for Swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swifty-json, xcode8

I downloaded the supposed Swift 3.0 compatible SwiftyJSON from [here](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/tree/swift3)

I am getting countless errors as a result and moving to Swift 3.0 has turned into a nightmare. The last commit on the git repo was made some 3 months ago. Using XCode 8. 
Is there any compatible SwiftyJSON for Swift 3.0?

[image: ERRORS #1]

[image: ERRORS #2]